# Multiple table Fulltext search against two php variables

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have three tables of information where the business_id is the common thread.  I have two input fields, one for general search (users can search for whatever they want) and a zip input. On the php side, I catch the general search string and set it to `$search` and the zip set to `$zip`.

How can I use the `$search` variable to `MATCH` any of the fulltext indecies ***then*** limit those matches using the `$zip` ***then*** return only the id from table c?

My database structure is below:

```
table coup
    id  << this is the my desired information from the search
    timestamp
    business_id
    coupvalue
    startdate
    enddate
    username
    status
    terms
    image
    description
        primary = id
        fulltext = name
table bloc
    id
    address
    city
    state
    zip
    business_id
    phone
    lat
    lon
        primary = id
table bus
    business_id
    name
    timestamp
    category
    subcat
        primary = business_id
        fulltext = name,category,subcat
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `or` condition with the matches:

```
select
    c.id
from
    coup c
    inner join bus b on
        c.business_id = b.business_id
    inner join block z on
        c.buisness_id = z.business_id
    where
        (match(c.name) against ('$search')
        or match (b.name, b.category, b.subcat) against ('$search'))
        and z.zip = '$zip'
```

I haven't benchmarked it, but this could potentially be faster:

```
select
   c.id
from
    (select id, business_id 
     from coup 
     where match(name) against ('$search')
    ) as c
    left join
       (select business_id 
        from bus 
        where match(name, category, subcat) against ('$search')
       ) as b on
        c.business_id = b.business_id 
    inner join bloc z on
        c.business_id = z.business_id
where
    z.zip = '$zip'
```

Comment: I'd like to add c.name,b.category,b.subcat to the match too though.

Comment: Full text searches only work across their respective indices. You can't do a multi-table full text index, in so far as I know.